# Post request without headers

Tags: next.js, fastapi

I am working on a next js application in which i need to send a formdata to fastapi end point but it showed unprocessable entry

PS:- I added headers in fetch function now I am able to post data, I just need to know why should i include headers for the post request I did not use such when working in vue js

next js Page

```
'use client'

import { useRef} from "react"

export default function Add() {

    var taskname=useRef("")
    var expense=useRef("")
    var formData=useRef({
        task: taskname,
        expense: expense
    })

    function handleClick(){
  
        formData.current.task=taskname.current.value
        formData.current.expense=expense.current.value
        var a=JSON.stringify(formData.current)
        fetch("http://localhost:8000",{
            method: "POST",
              body: a
        }).then((response)=>{
            if (response.ok == true){
                console.log("Success")
            }
            else{
                console.log("failed")
            }
        })
    }
 
    return (
        <form name="addtask" className="flex flex-col gap-2 items-center justify-center bg-slate-400 p-7">
            <p>Welcome to add page</p>

            <textarea name="task" ref={taskname} placeholder="Enter the task here:" rows={2} cols={30} className="resize-none focus:outline-none border border-black rounded-md p-2" >
            </textarea>
            <input type="text" ref={expense} name="expense" placeholder="Expense" className="focus:outline-none border border-black p-2 flex w-full rounded-sm"/>
            <input type="button" onClick={()=>{handleClick()}} value={"Add Task"} className="flex text-blue-950 bg-white border border-blue-950 transition-colors ease-in duration-200 hover:bg-blue-950 hover:text-white items-center justify-center p-1 w-full text-lg rounded-sm" />

        </form>

    )
}
```

Fast api main.py

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware


origins = [
    
    "http://localhost:3000",
]




app = FastAPI()

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

class Data(BaseModel):
    task: str
    expense: str


@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}


@app.post("/add")
def add(data: Data):
    print(data)
```